# Wrong Number of LSTM Dimensions in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to classify texts using Recurrent Neural Networks and am facing issue while implementing the following Python Code (backend is on TensorFlow):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Embedding
import numpy
import pandas as pd

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

raw_data = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx',sep=',')
df = raw_data.iloc[:,0:2]
df['Input']=df['Input'].astype(str)

X = df['Input'].values
X = pd.get_dummies(X).as_matrix() # Convert Dataframe to Nd-Araay

Y = df['Output'].values
Y = pd.get_dummies(Y).as_matrix() # Convert Dataframe to Nd-Araay

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(450, input_shape =(X.shape[0], X.shape[1])))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100,verbose=0)    

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\nLoss: %.2f, Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (loss, accuracy*100))
```

My input ie X is an Nd Array consisting of 411 rows & 407 columns while Y consists of 411 rows & 7 columns and following is the error I am getting:

```
expected lstm_input_43 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (411, 407)
```

Comment: I think it's because LSTM layer is waiting for a vector like this :
(Number of samples, Number of words in your text, Value representing your words)

You should look at the embedding layer for text classification with LSTM under keras.

Comment: Could you provide us more details about your data input format?